# VSCode not showing Github CoPilot shortcuts and prev/next options

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I recently installed Github CoPilot extension in my VSCode editor (v1.76.1) on Ubuntu 20.04. I am able to trigger inline suggestions using `Alt + \`, but I am unable to use `Alt + [ or Alt + ]` shortcuts to navigate between suggestions. Additionally, when I hover over the inline suggestion, I don't see the "prev" and "next" options.

I have confirmed that I am running the latest version of CoPilot (`v1.77.9225`) and CoPilot Labs (`v0.12.791`). I have also checked my keyboard shortcut settings for Github CoPilot and they seem to be correct (see attached photo).

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Any suggestions on how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Attached photos:

[image: Screenshot showing cursor over inline suggestion without prev/next options]

Screenshot showing keyboard shortcut settings for Github CoPilot:
[image: Screenshot showing keyboard shortcut settings for Github CoPilot]

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using the VIM plugin, wondering if that may be interfering?

Comment: They weird thing is that sometimes it works though (mostly it does not). I have not observed a clear pattern yet.

Comment: @Simon I guess not. I was using it also, but there was no effect after disabling it.

Comment: Same issue here. I'm using MX Linux 21.3 (based on Debian 11.6).

Comment: Which desktop environment or window manager are you using? I am on i3.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to set these two shortcuts here (which were unset on my VSCodium installation):

[image]

FWIW, this is what gets added to `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
    "key": "alt+9",
    "command": "editor.action.inlineSuggest.showNext"
},
{
    "key": "alt+8",
    "command": "editor.action.inlineSuggest.showPrevious"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add or change setting.json this line like this:

```
"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In settings.json, delete this line of code:

```
"editor.inlineSuggest.showToolbar": "always",
```

settings.json can be opened by clicking `Edit in settings.json` in Github Copilot settings under File > Preferences > Settings > Extensions > Copilot in VSCode.
[image]

Now, the inline suggestions toolbar should show.

Read more: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75#_redesigned-inline-suggestions-toolbar